# VBA Code Running in debugging mode but not in runtime

Tags: excel, vba

```
    Public myHTTP As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Sub SendXML()
    Dim response As String 
    Dim MyXmlHttpHandler As CXMLHTTPHandler 
    Dim myxml As String 
    Dim a As String
    Dim URL2 As String 
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim NewFile As Object
    Dim XMLFileText As String

    If Not myHTTP Is Nothing Then Set myHTTP = Nothing

    Set myHTTP = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set MyXmlHttpHandler = New CXMLHTTPHandler
    MyXmlHttpHandler.Initialize myHTTP
    myHTTP.OnReadyStateChange = MyXmlHttpHandler
    myxml = "D:\1.xml"
    myHTTP.Open "get", myxml, True
    myHTTP.send (myxml)
    a = myHTTP.responseText
    URL2=Workbooks("MainSheet.xlsm").Worksheets("OTHERS").Range("I2").Value
    If Workbooks("MainSheet.xlsm").Worksheets("OTHERS").Range("h2").Value = vbNullString Or Workbooks("MainSheet.xlsm").Worksheets("OTHERS").Range("h3").Value = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "User not defined server database address or port number...!!!" & vbNewLine & " Failed.."
    Exit Sub
    End If

    myHTTP.Open "POST", URL2, True
    myHTTP.send (a)

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set NewFile = FSO.CreateTextFile("D:\response.XML", 1, 1)
    XMLFileText = ""
    NewFile.write (XMLFileText & myHTTP.responseText & vbNewLine)  ‘---------error occurred here not printing my response.text in new file.

    End Sub
```

I have already tried on error resume next, it just printing a blank file.

I have also  tried on error goto errorhandler
but it also failed saying runtime error dialoge box....

I just want to save response text in a xml file without any error dialouge box..

Comment: what is the actual error msg? and at which line?

Comment: i want to write the response text in a new file which code is in last line but it showing runtime error -2147483638...

Comment: Getting a response takes time. When you go line by line it has enough time, in runtime not. Build in a second break or a waiting condition.

Comment: can you please provide the code how to do it..... i am a beginner in vba...

Comment: Is this a large file? Why use async wrapper this way? Why not simple xmlhttp POST request with False argument?

Comment: OK 1 minute i am trying....its not a large file....

Comment: Ok QHarr you just saved my time.....Thank you for your help......Thank you very much....   I just changed async wrapper  to false....now my code working perfectly....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future readers

Change the last argument from True to False

```
myHTTP.Open "POST", myxml, False
```

Allow time for completion

Comment: you have to change the last argument from true to false when posting... i.e          myHTTP.Open "post", myxml, false

Comment: I have amended to POST. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a large file? Why use async wrapper this way? Why not simple xmlhttp POST request with False argument? – QHarr 8 mins ago

this comment solved my error..... thnks

Comment: Assuming you only changed the argument it is sufficient an answer to put the True argument in  myHTTP.Open "get", myxml, True needs to be set to False i.e.  myHTTP.Open "get", myxml, False

Comment: sorry i forget to mention that if i set myHTTP.Open "get", myxml, false it showing me error so i set it as default (i.e. myHTTP.Open "get", myxml, True) but i have to change async to false when i am posting i.e. myHTTP.Open "POST", myxml, false